# Update live data (like progress bar) in view with Laravel 4

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

## TL;DR

> I would like to send data to update live in a view, such as a progress
>   bar showing the status of an action.
>   What is the best way to do that in laravel 4?

---

## The Setup

I'm working on a Laravel 4 based project where each user can redeem a serial key.

I've made an admin backend where I can easily paste in a list of keys, or upload a file of them.

Let's say `$key_string` is the string of newline-seperated keys that I've uploaded, and want to parse out to then upload the contained key strings from - here is the simplified code that adds the keys:

```
$key_string = rtrim($key_string);
$key_string = str_replace("\n\r", "\n", $key_string);
$keys = explode( "\n", $key_string);

foreach($keys as $index => $key) {
    Key::create(
        array( "serial" => trim($key) )
    );
}
```

Since the sets of keys I upload number in the thousands, this can sometimes take a good 30 seconds, during which time the admin panel naturally doesn't show anything.

Now, I don't mind it taking this time. I don't need to optimize the upload to use one query, etc, but I would like to have some actual feedback so I know how far the upload has gone.

---

## The Question

When I upload keys, I would like to be able to update a progress bar or counter in my view every few seconds or percent ticks (using the current `$index`)

Is there an easy way to handle this painlessly, preferably integrated in Laravel 4? I'm assuming this would involve ajax, but can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With PHP there are really two options without going to Web Sockets or Push-Pull setups.  This isn't really a Laravel thing it's more of an AJAX loop that requests JSON "thing".

**Short polling**

Olark uses this methodology for their chat script.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON("/path", function(data) {
        // update the view with your fresh data
    });
}, 5000);
```

**Long polling**

Javascript

```
var eventName = function() {
    $.getJSON("/path", function(data) {
        // update the view with your fresh data
        if (data.progress < 100)
            eventName();
    });
};
```

Controller Logic

I use this when I have users upload a CSV and are waiting for it to finish uploading and be processed.

```
// in your controller
$check = true;
while ($check) {
    // search database
    // compare values
    if ($newDataWasFound)
        $check = false;

    $progressFromAbove = 90;
}

return Response::json(array(
    'newData' => $array,
    'progress' => $progressFromAbove,
));
```

I made a screencast on this using Laravel 3 but Long Polling is PHP relevant not Laravel.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDgJF77jELo

**Examples**

- https://gist.github.com/clouddueling/5239153
- https://gist.github.com/clouddueling/6296036

Comment: Interesting. Is there any resource you would advise that does a clear job of outlining the difference between short and long poling, and when to use either? I'd prefer something that starts a simple project from scratch.

Comment: @Johannes Unfortunately in my experience not really. For PHP the internet was kind of scattered with tattered examples of this stuff.  I'll get some more examples in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could put it in Session and get it from another link.

```
$key_string = rtrim($key_string);
$key_string = str_replace("\n\r", "\n", $key_string);
$keys = explode( "\n", $key_string);

$count = 0;
foreach($keys as $key) {
  Key::create(
      array( "serial" => trim($key) )
  );
  $count++;
  if($count % 5== 0) Session::put('count',$count);
}


//route.php
Route::get('/count', function()
{
   if( Session::has('count'))
        return Session::get('count');
});
```

Comment: you may call "/count" by ajax.

Comment: Hmm, so I would call the ajax code every X seconds? Or is there any better way of doing that only when the data has actually updated?

Comment: No way. you should call every X seconds. because web is stateless yet.
It means that server couldn't send data without request from client.
WebSocket as part of HTML5 is going to provide it but it's not fully support yet.

Comment: alright, I guess an easy easy way of handeling this would be for the server to store when the last time it updated data was, and then you have ajax query for that, and only if you see that there has been an update, would you query for the other stuff. Thanks for the useful answer and code. +1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373373/jqueryui-progress-bar might help.  You'd have to do some math to figure out how much of the bar to fill out depending on the count and the total.  Once it reaches 100, use clearInterval() to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you code using Laravel or Core PHP, you should give [Server sent events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) a try. It is easily doable using SSE.

It basically includes two parts:-

**1. Javascript API (Client side)** - You will have to subscribe to an event stream, create an EventSource object and pass it the URL of your stream like this:-

```
if (!!window.EventSource) {
  var source = new EventSource('stream.php');
} else {
  // Result to xhr polling :(
}
```

Then setting up a handler for the message event. You can optionally listen for open and error:-

```
source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log(e.data);
}, false);

source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
  // Connection was opened.
}, false);

source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
  if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
    // Connection was closed.
  }
}, false);
```

**2. PHP (Server side )** - You will have to send `Content-Type: text/event-stream` header and then push the response as and when processed, in predefined format like this:-

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); // recommended to prevent caching of event data.

/**
 * Constructs the SSE data format and flushes that data to the client.
 *
 * @param string $id Timestamp/id of this connection.
 * @param string $msg Line of text that should be transmitted.
 */
function sendMsg($id, $msg) {
  echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
  echo "data: $msg" . PHP_EOL;
  echo PHP_EOL;
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}

$serverTime = time();

sendMsg($serverTime, 'server time: ' . date("h:i:s", time()));
```

This all snippets is borrowed from aforementioned link and a thorough study is recommended for crystal clear understanding.

Cheers