# How to get a progress bar for downloading a file via Storage Facade (in Laravel 5)?

Tags: laravel, download, progress-bar, storage

Hello this is my code used for downloading a file with Laravel5 and Storage Facade for virtual disks (pretty simple):

```
//implemented as a Artisan Console command
$contents = Storage::disk('remoteDisk')->get($filePath);
Storage::disk('csv')->put($filePathTarget, $contents);
```

Well I'd like to see a progress bar in the output like the documentation suggests:

```
$bar = $this->output->createProgressBar($count);
//do something
$bar->advance();
//i'm done
$bar->finish();
```

Since the Storage method get() isn't a loop, how can I "advance" the progress bar?

The initialization could be:

```
  $size_remote = Storage::disk('remoteDisk')->size($filePath);
  $size = Storage::disk('csv')->size($filePath);
```

But how/where do I get the temporary file filesize to advance the Progress bar during the download?

Comment: You likely can't as the Storage facade doesn't use a stream for reading. If it were to use a stream you could build a context and use `stream_notification_callback` with the `STREAM_NOTIFY_PROGRESS` code. You could do it with Flysystem but it doesn't look like you can use it through the storage facade.

Answer (score 0):

It's doable, but you are going to need JavaScript.

Also it's been answered already on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344343/update-live-data-like-progress-bar-in-view-with-laravel-4).