# Laravel writing to session periodically in a loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel, so my knowledge is limited.

I'm modifying an existing script that imports CSV rows into a relational database. Works fine, however as the usual CSV row count is typically in the region of 150k, it can take some time to process, so I want to provide progress feedback to the user via the UI.

In my script, I have the following which writes to the session, and another ajax script periodically gets the progress by reading the session data.

```
//To prevent too much unnecessary session writing, let's update the session every 50 records
    if($this->lineNumber % 50 == 0) {
        $this->request->session()->put('csvImportProgress',json_encode(["currentRecord"=>$this->lineNumber,"totalRecords"=>$recordCount]));
    }
```

The session does update, but not as expected. It only updates when the upload has completed.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you might want to rethink your approach: For example, why don't you chunk the rows (paginate) and process them in smaller batches. But in order to come up with a better design, we / you should first know what the goal exactly is.

Comment: As said, you may need to rethink your approach to this. You could initialise the upload over ajax, and have the script return progress, then update the progress for the user that way... just 1 option of many. More info may help us help you :) - Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344343/update-live-data-like-progress-bar-in-view-with-laravel-4?rq=1